# Rendering update to update panel despite of validator presence

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have an asp.net update panel in my page and I set a trigger to update the panel. There are also some required field outside the update panel which is linked with some validator. I am using the AsyncPostBack Trigger which is supposed to update only the update panel contents, but when I clicking the trigger, the valdator is triggered and stopping even the partial postback. But I need to update the update panel irrespective of the requied field.  I want the validation when there is a full postback which will be handled by some other button. how can I do that? Any help...

```
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="validatormsg" ErrorMessage="Please enter Ad description" ControlToValidate="AdSummaryTextBox">
                  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Some value I want to update here and Trigger is also in this region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Set CausesValidation to false in the control that triggers the updatepanel.